# Create a function that accepts and returns list of the keys in the objects

Tags: javascript

I am supposed to create a function that accepts an object as an argument and returns a list of the keys in the provided object.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
function keyGenerator() {
  let obj1 = {
    color: "black",
    inkColor: "blue",
    brand: "Bic"
  }
  let obj2 = {
    name: "weight",
    weight: 230,
    height: 6.2
  }
  let keys = Object.keys(obj1, obj2);
  console.log(keys);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your function doesn’t accept an argument

Comment: The requirement sounds like it's essentially `Object.keys()`. Are you supposed to create this function without using that?

Comment: Also, *"an object"* or ***"multiple objects"***? And also, what is exactly the expected result?

Comment: Otherwise seems as simple as `const keys = Object.keys({...obj1, ...obj2});` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: And also, take the argument as required by the task!: `keyGenerator(oneObject) { return Object.keys(oneObject); }` and you're done. Use like: `console.log( keyGenerator({...obj1, ...obj2}) );`

Answer (score 1):

Given your task:

- *"function accepts an argument Object"* (presumably only one argument)

and your question title:

- *"returns list of the keys in the objects"* (therefore join your multipls objects into one using [Destructuring assignment `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment))

```js
function keyGenerator(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj);
}
// or shorter: 
// const keyGenerator = Object.keys;

const obj1 = {
  color: "black",
  inkColor: "blue",
  brand: "Bic"
}

const obj2 = {
  name: "weight",
  weight: 230,
  height: 6.2
}

const result = keyGenerator({...obj1, ...obj2});
console.log(result);
```

which returns:

```js
[
  "color",
  "inkColor",
  "brand",
  "name",
  "weight",
  "height"
]
```

Comment: Shorter: `const keyGenerator = Object.keys`

Comment: @AdamJenkins yes exactly, thank you